# W.M.Player конец трека

Tags: c#

Есть:

```
public static WindowsMediaPlayer WMPs = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
```

Есть timer1 некая процедура проигрывает трек
Есть еще:

```
        if (ЧТО-ТО)
        {
            int i;
            i = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            i++;
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
            PlayURL(array[listBox1.SelectedIndex], 2);
            PlayURL(array[listBox1.SelectedIndex], 1);            
        }
```

Вместо "ЧТО-ТО" должно стоять
"Если трек закончился, то выполняется код ниже"
Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш подход неправилен.

Вы не должны пытаться по таймеру поймать момент, когда трек закончился. Вы должны подписаться на событие, и должным образом реагировать.

Вы не указали, откуда именно взялся ваш `WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer`, поэтому предположу, что вы имеете в виду [этот](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562388(v=vs.85).aspx). В документации упомянуты события, которые отправляются, когда состояние плейера меняется: [`PlayStateChange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562460(v=vs.85).aspx). Подпишитесь на него и реагируйте так, как вам нужно. Если у вас включен autoplay, проще будет, наверное, подписаться на изменение текущего трека: [`CurrentItemChange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562403(v=vs.85).aspx).